# jaxWS issue on Netbeans 6.5 and Glassfish V2

Tags: soap, netbeans, glassfish, netbeans6.5

i am not able to build Web Service Client, it is showing an error msg :**You are running on JDK6 which comes with JAX-WS 2.1 API, but this tool requires JAX-WS 2.2 API. Use the endorsed standards override mechanism (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/), or set xendorsed="true" on . 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)**

can any one help me out to solve this ...
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: The error message has an explanation about how to use the endorsed override mechanism. Essentially you download JAX-WS 2.2 and place the jars in the endorsed library in your JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Unix?  Is the wsimport in your path in the glassfish directory or the Java install directory?  I seem to remember getting this and changing my path so I got the wsimport from glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know main cause but i think sometimes IDE causes that. Deleting WS reference and adding ws client again works for me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on netbeans generated error link (by clicking on it, netbeans will open jaxws-build.xml & goes to wsimport tag definition line) & add attribute `xendorsed="true"` somewhere in "wsimport" tag.
Or you can download & add JAX-WS 2.2 API jar file in your project classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Check the JDK configuration being ran by the IDE,

When using Netbeans,

**Step 1:**

> Find the Netbeans.conf file (C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans7.0\etc\netbeans.conf)

**Step 2:**

> Change "netbeans_jdkhome" to point to the newer JDK (i.e.
>   netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80")

**Note: Try similar steps for other IDEs**